# Generate cron job output in html file

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have already set up cron job through my website control panel. I get the output on my email. 
But I want to display the output in a particular html file. 
Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Can you try going to this URL `http://www.yoursite.com/cron/cron_exec.php`, replace the `www.yoursite.com` with your URL.

Comment: Add a mock command here!

Answer (score 0):

How do you email the results? Is this a php script that sends the email?

If so, you can easily use the php function fopen() and fwrite() to create a file and write to it, instead of sending a mail.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: ..Using `cPanel` (from the tags). `cPanel` handles the mail part.

Comment: No it is not php script . It is through website cpanel . It allows us to set up cron job manually through form. It asks us to add email and sends the output on the assigned email

Comment: I don't think its possible through cPanel, and since you used the tag of PHP, you should create the HTML file through the PHP script.

Comment: @BartVanDenBoomen According to the user `"I get the output on my email"`.

Comment: @activatedGeek do you have any idea??

Comment: Actually I want to tell you ..why i am using the cron for my website. I need to  create a pop up about which course is going to be started . I want the cron to run the code every 30 minutes so that i get the pop up. for getting pop up i need to display the output generated in html format.

Comment: @enjal Add the command to your question. Edit your question and then I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

In cPanel, the cron job will email you the output by default. To get it to send HTML emails, you have to add 'CONTENT_TYPE="text/html; charset=utf-8"' to the file located at /var/spool/cron/user. I added it below the MAILTO= line and now the output of my cron jobs are emailed in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

In crontab system :

- /usr/bin/php is php binary path (different in some systems ex:
  freebsd
- /usr/local/bin/php, linux: /usr/bin/php)
- /home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php should be your php script
  path
- /dev/null should be cron output , ex: /home/username/stdoutx.txt

So you can monitor your cron by viewing cron output /home/username/stdoutx.txt